# how can I reflect/flip a picture around when loading

Tags: coronasdk

I know how to rotate the picture but i want to flip it, e.g. a if someone is looking to the  left, I dont want to have to load another picture for him to look to the right ?

help Corona !

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Scale to flip object

```
object.xScale = -1  to flip right,left or

object.yScale = -1 to flip up,down
```

Comment: of course I can .. i was using this in Flash .. but somehow couldnt find anything in the corona sdk.
works a treat ..
Thank you DevfaR !